# -Tainda form - explanation please

Tags: potential-form, volitional-form

There is this lyric

> 何から逃れたいんだ
>   現実ってやつか

Where 逃れたいんだ seems like its the -tai form. How should I translate this?

Comment: I don't understand where て comes in.  Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: It just looks like it might be a te form, but I'm sure that's the case. How would you translate that?

Comment: Why do you think it's in て form? たい's て form is たくて.

Comment: It tried writing an answer but I'm not sure if the OP will be satisfied with it... If we knew why she thought it was the -te form in the first place it would help in explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As people have mentioned in the comments, the -te form doesn't come into this.

Here we have the ichidan verb [逃]{のが}れる, 'to escape'. So the -tai form would be 逃れたい, which is what we see in the lyrics.
The same conjugation as, for example, 食べる→食べたい where you just replace `る` with `たい`.

> 何から逃れたいんだ
>   What do you want to get away from?
>   現実ってやつか
>   (That thing called) reality?

As @Nothing at all says, `-tai` + `-te form` would be `たくて`.

For example, 現実から逃れ**たくて**漫画を読む - to read manga because(-te) you want(-tai) to get away from reality.

edit: it seems OP completely changed the initial question. This answer talks about the -te form so much because the initial question was "-Tai form with -te form? explanation please"

Comment: マイナス２になってんだけどｗｗオレなんかまずいことでも言った？？

Comment: おお・・でも巻き返した！ (^ ^)/~

Answer (score 1):

何から逃れたいんだ
From what do you want to escape?

現実ってやつか
Reality?

-tai form correspond to want in English.

verb conjugation
逃れる(normal)->逃れたい(want)

e.g
I want have sandwich for lunch.
私はサンドイッチをランチに'食べたい'と思います

verb conjugation
食べる(normal)->食べたい(want)